# Sorting or searching by several conditions

Tags: c#

I have a class StationInfo with properties:

```
public uint EnergyConsumption { get; private set; }
public uint CurrentEnergyAmount { get; private set; }
public uint NumRobotsNearStation { get; private set; }
public uint NumStationsAround { get; private set; }
```

i'm creating an array of StationInfo type.

In this array i need to find an object that satisfies the following condition simultaneously:

```
EnergyConsumption -> min
CurrentEnergyAmount -> max
NumRobotsNearStation -> min
NumStationsAround -> max
```

Example with 2 arguments:

```
{2,1}
{3,4}
{6,7}
{1,10}
{2, 15}
```

need to find `{min, max}`

no objects with this condition, but exist object with near values to min and max is `{2, 15}`

Has C# turnkey solutions to solve this problem ?

Comment: Yes, like `list.Where(x => x.EnergyConsumption==min && .....);`

Comment: You cannot minimize/maximize multiple different variables.  Do you want to find four objects; the ones with the min/max of each of those four fields?

Comment: ... are min and max known values or they have to be found? and what happens if none of the elements satisfies your condition ( one property does, but the others don't)?

Comment: What should be returned if the max and min values are stored in different `StationInfo` objects? Then no one of them would meet the condition.

Comment: not necessarily equal to those values. those values ​​should approximates to min or max

Comment: @eradMan Okay, how close is close enough?  With 1, with 1%, within a value/percentage specified to the method?  Are you looking to minimize the sum of the difference between each item's value and it's optimal value?  You need to be much more specific about what this should do.  Explain how a person would be able to determine the right answer and we may be able to help you turn that into something a computer can understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
var filtered = myArray.Where(a => a.EnergyConsumption == min 
   && a.CurrentEnergyAmount == max
   && a.NumRobotNearStation == max
   && a.NumStationsAround == min)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is improbable that a station fulfills all these criteria at the same time. It would probably make more sense to return all the stations which fulfill at least one of the criteria.

```
uint minEnergyConsumption = stations.Min(s => s.EnergyConsumption);
uint maxCurrentEnergyAmount = stations.Max(s => s.CurrentEnergyAmount);
uint maxNumRobotsNearStation = stations.Max(s => s.NumRobotsNearStation);
uint minNumStationsAround = stations.Min(s => s.NumStationsAround);

var result = stations
    .Where(s => s.EnergyConsumption == minEnergyConsumption ||
                s.CurrentEnergyAmount == maxCurrentEnergyAmount ||
                s.NumRobotNearStation == maxNumRobotsNearStation ||
                s.NumStationsAround == minNumStationsAround);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Comparer to Sort according your conditions:

```
stations.Sort( new StationsComparer() );
```

where StationsComparer is:

```
class StationsComparer: IComparer<StationInfo>
{
    public int Compare( StationInfo x, StationInfo y )
    {
        int result = x.EnergyConsumption.CompareTo( y.EnergyConsumption );

        if( result == 0 )
            result = y.CurrentEnergyAmount.CompareTo( x.CurrentEnergyAmount );

        if( result == 0 )
            result = y.NumRobotNearStation.CompareTo( x.NumRobotNearStation );

        if( result == 0 )
            result = x.NumStationsAround.CompareTo( y.NumStationsAround );

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this 2-pass solution is about a good as you'll get.

- 1 pass to find the minimum values for each interesting attribute
- 1 pass to find the matching item (if any)

  ```
  StationInfo FindMin( IEnumerable<StationInfo> stations )
  {
    uint minEnergyConsumption    = uint.MaxValue ;
    uint maxCurrentEnergyAmount  = uint.MinValue ;
    uint minNumRobotsNearStation = uint.MaxValue ;
    uint maxNumStationsAround    = uint.MinValue ;

    // find the min value for each interesting field
    foreach ( StationInfo si in stations )
    {
      minEnergyConsumption    = si.EnergyConsumption    < minEnergyConsumption    ? si.EnergyConsumption    : minEnergyConsumption    ;
      maxCurrentEnergyAmount  = si.CurrentEnergyAmount  > maxCurrentEnergyAmount  ? si.CurrentEnergyAmount  : maxCurrentEnergyAmount  ;
      minNumRobotsNearStation = si.NumRobotsNearStation < minNumRobotsNearStation ? si.NumRobotsNearStation : minNumRobotsNearStation ;
      maxNumStationsAround    = si.NumStationsAround    > maxNumStationsAround    ? si.NumStationsAround    : maxNumStationsAround    ;
    }

    StationInfo instance = stations.FirstOrDefault( x =>
         x.EnergyConsumption    == minEnergyConsumption 
      && x.CurrentEnergyAmount  == maxCurrentEnergyAmount
      && x.NumRobotsNearStation == minNumRobotsNearStation
      && x.NumStationsAround    == maxNumStationsAround
    );
    return instance ;
  }
  ```